# Failure rendering foreignObject inside SVG leveraging d3

Tags: javascript, svg, coffeescript, d3.js

I have read the posts related and feel like my code is accurate; I have tried numerous mutations of this code as well. I am in hopes that someone can find what I am sure is a minor error in my code as I have had no luck detecting it.

Problem: Contents of foreignObject element not rendering in browser visually. DOM elements are  apparently inserted into DOM but not visible.

I notice that in Chrome web developer that the foreignObject element is not camelcase in the element inspector however upon editing the html inline it is editable as camelcase, so evidently the element is held as camelcase. This likely has no impact on the issue but thought I would mention it.

DOM after executing:

```
<g class="component" transform="translate(75,20)">
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red" opacity="1">
    <foreignObject width="100" height="100" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow;" data-uid="special_uid">
        </div>
      </body>
    </foreignObject>
  </rect>
</g>
```

D3 SVG/XHTML generation code (CoffeeScript):

```
  component = canvas.select("[data-uid=#{entityObj.name}]").selectAll('.component')
    .data(entityObj.components)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .each( (componentObj,i,d) => 
      @generateAssociationLocalCache(entityObj,componentObj,i,d)
      @generateComponentLocalCache(entityObj,componentObj,i,d)
    )
    .attr("data-uid", (o,i,d)-> o.name)
    .attr("id", (o,i,d)-> o.name)
    .attr("class", "component")
    .attr("transform", (componentObj,i,d) => 
      coords = @rows[entityObj.name]['components'][componentObj.uid]
      "translate(#{coords.x},#{coords["y#{i}"]})"
    )  
    .append("rect")  
    .attr("width", (componentObj,i,d) => componentObj.width)
    .attr("height", @get('component').height)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("opacity", "1")
    .append("foreignObject")  
    .attr("width", (componentObj,i,d) => componentObj.width)
    .attr("height", @get('component').height)
    .attr("requiredExtensions", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .append("body")
    .attr("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .append("div")
    .attr("style", (componentObj,i,d) => "width: #{componentObj.width}px; height: #{@get('component').height}px; background-color: yellow;")
    .attr("data-uid", (o,i,d) -> o.uid)
```

[image: Rendered rect element]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got at least 2 issues. Firstly `<foreignObject>` can't be a child of a `<rect>` element. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but you probably need to split up the code

```
  var g = component.append("g")
    .each( (componentObj,i,d) => 
      @generateAssociationLocalCache(entityObj,componentObj,i,d)
      @generateComponentLocalCache(entityObj,componentObj,i,d)
    )
    .attr("data-uid", (o,i,d)-> o.name)
    .attr("id", (o,i,d)-> o.name)
    .attr("class", "component")
    .attr("transform", (componentObj,i,d) => 
      coords = @rows[entityObj.name]['components'][componentObj.uid]
      "translate(#{coords.x},#{coords["y#{i}"]})"
    )
```

and then do

```
g.append("rect")  
.attr("width", (componentObj,i,d) => componentObj.width)
.attr("height", @get('component').height)
.attr("fill", "red")
.attr("opacity", "1");

g.append("foreignObject")
...
```

which would make the rect and foreignObject siblings.

secondly xmlns not an attribute you can set after the object has been created so

```
.append("body")
  .attr("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
```

should be

```
.append("xhtml:body")
```

d3 will then create the element in the correct namespace.

Comment: Robert, thanks for quick response. 

I don't really care about the containing rect, just wanted to see my alignment for the object.

    <g class="component" transform="translate(525,20)">
      <foreignObject width="100" height="100" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <body>
          <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow;" data-uid="bearer_setup_suc_rate_s5_s8"></div>
        </body>
      </foreignObject>
    </g>

Comment: Best create something we can run then like a jsfiddle otherwise it's rather hard to debug.

Comment: Yeah, in progress. 1 moment.

Comment: Your general statements above were the issue. I misunderstood potential usage for foreignObject in SVG (still don't really know its usage, took different route to same ends). Technique used was sourced from http://vallandingham.me/building_a_bubble_cloud.html Thanks!

Comment: A great answer, but I think that creating the foreign object in the proper namespace is the more fundamental issue and should be place first. The issue with placing a foreignObject inside a 'rect' is a just about well-formed svg, but initially creating the body element in the correct namespace is a unique issue with using d3. If you came to this answer like me, be sure to read all of the way to the last two lines!